# GraphQL API - mutations of nested objects

Tags: graphql, api-design

Let assume that I have 2 types that are managed via GraphQL API:

```
type Parent {
    id: ID
    name: String
    children: [Child!]  
}

type Child {
    id: ID
    name: String
}

query {
    parents(): Parent
}

mutations {
    addParent(in: ParentInput!): Parent!
    addChild(parentID: ID!, in: ChildInput!): Child!
    updateChild(childID:ID!, in: ChildInput!): Child!
}
```

Now, I am wondering what arguments should accept `updateChild`.
In the example above, the only `childID` is required. Do you think it is acceptable to also require from users providing `parentID`?

```
updateChild(childID:ID!, parentID: ID!, in: ChildInput)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the suggestion from [here](https://blog.apollographql.com/designing-graphql-mutations-e09de826ed97) which each mutation only has one input object argument which consolidate all the necessary fields rather than flattening these fields into many different input arguments. Also I tend to have one input object for each mutation (Github mutation API also use such design style)

So for the `updateChild` mutation , I would have the following input type :

```
mutations {
    updateChild(input: UpdateChildInput): Child
} 

input UpdateChildInput {
    childId : ID!
    parentId: ID
    name:String 
}
```

What fields to be included in the `UpdateChildInput` depends on your API requirements. Include the fields that your API need to support. So if your API allows user to change the parent of a child , you have to include it in the input.

Please note that parentID and the name are optional , which means if user does not specify them , they will not be updated.